# Finding the knee point in an eigenvalue plot

Tags: pca, svd, eigenvalue

I want to automatically find the "knee" point of the eigenvalue plot. I.e. I have a vector of eigenvalues (sorted from highest to lowest) and I want some heuristic to find the "knee" point.

Is there some heuristic for doing that

I've found the two following proposals so far.

1. Setting a threshold, say 0.99, or 0.95 and keep m of n eigenvalues when T(m-1) < 0.99 *T(n) <= T(m) where T(m) = sum(i=1:m){lambda(i)}
2. The knee is located at a point where the radius of curvature is a local minimum. For a curve y = f(x) the curvature is k = y''/(1+(y')^2)^(3/2). Just replace the derivatives with finite differences.

What do you think of these two proposals? How can I implement the second one? I don't understand how to replace the derivatives with the differences

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also check out the other SO sites on maths and programming.

Comment: @DavidBrossard: I've found the two following proposals so far.

1. Setting a threshold, say 0.99, or 0.95 and keep m of n eigenvalues when

T(m-1) < 0.99 *T(n) <= T(m)

where

T(m) = sum(i=1:m){lambda(i)}


2. The knee is located at a point where the radius of curvature.
is a local minimum. For a curve y = f(x) the curvature is

k = y''/(1+(y')^2)^(3/2).

Just replace the derivatives with finite differences.


What do you think of these two proposals?

How can I implement the second one? I don't understand how to replace the derivatives with the differences.

Comment: Hi, edit your question with your two proposals. Unfortunately, I cannot help you much but do check out http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think you should be able to approximate the derivative numerically by just subtracting the values. `y'(x_i)  = y(x_i) - y(x_(i-1))`. `y''(x_i) = y'(x_i) - y'(x_(i-1))`. `_` is subscript.

Answer (score -1):

Did you read this paper?

Non-Graphical Solutions for Cattell’s Scree Test
https://ppw.kuleuven.be/okp/_pdf/Raiche2013NGSFC.pdf